# Data Modeling With Multiple Links to Same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to plan out a data model in a postgres DB for a rails app, but I want to save myself the most time possible in the future for running queries. Here's my plan:

I have USERS, PRESENTATIONS, and RATINGS. USERS can both attend PRESENTATIONS or actually present. So USERS can "have many" PRESENTATIONS but in two different ways. USERS (presenters) and PRESENTATIONS will be one to many, while USERS (attendees) and PRESENTATIONS will be many to many.

Then there are RATINGS. A PRESENTATION has many RATINGS. All RATINGS also belong to USERS in two ways. USERS (attendees) have all the RATINGS they've submitted about a PRESENTATION, while USERS (presenters) have RATINGS about PRESENTATIONS where they've presented. In either case USERS have many RATINGS through PRESENTATIONS.

Is that the best data model to set this up? I've graphically depicted it below in case that's easier to visualize:

```
USERS
- HAS MANY presentations as an attendee - M2M
- HAS MANY presentations as a presenter
- HAS MANY ratings (through presentations) as an attendee
- HAS MANY ratings (through presentations) as an presenter

PRESENTATIONS
- BELONGS TO attendee user - M2M
- BELONGS TO presenter user
- HAS MANY ratings

RATINGS
- BELONGS TO presentations
- BELONGS TO attendee user through presentations
- BELONGS TO presenter user through presentations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do separate association tables for each type of action. You could probably just add a `presenter_id` column to the `presentations` table since you're describing a `has_one` relationship for `presenters`, but having a separate association model allows you the flexibility of making it a `has_many` relationship in the future if you choose to support presentations with multiple presenters.

With the following configuration, you can call `presentation.presenter` to receive the user who presented. or `presentation.attendees` to receive the list of users who attended. Or on the flip side, `user.attended_presentations` to receive the list of presentations they have attended, or `user.presented_presentations` to receive the list of presentations they presented at. Feel free to name the association tables whatever you feel makes the most sense.

```
# User.rb
has_many :presentation_attendees
has_many :attended_presentations, through: :presentation_attendees, source: :presentation
has_many :presentation_presenters
has_many :presented_presentations, through: :presentation_presenters, source: :presentation

# Presentation.rb
has_many :presentation_attendees
has_many :attendees, through: :presentation_attendees, source: :user
has_one :presentation_presenter
has_one :presenter, through: :presentation_presenter, source: :user

# PresentationPresenter.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :presentation

# PresentationAttendee.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :presentation
```

As for ratings, you can just have them `belongs_to :presentation` and `belongs_to :user`, so that you can pull up a list of all ratings by a user with `user.ratings` or all ratings for a presentation with `presentation.ratings`, and then you could add a public instance method on the `User` class to retrieve all ratings for presentations they have presented at:

```
# User.rb
def presentation_ratings
  presented_presentations.map(&:rating)
end
```

Hope that helps!